# Unix variable assignment inside shell

Tags: shell, unix, variable-assignment

New to unix, hopefully this is a very basic question, but I'm not sure what to look up.
I have a line command, below, which reads the first word of a text file.
`cut -d' ' -f1 timestep`

I need to run it inside a shell script and assign the string to a variable. Simply assigning this expression to a variable doesn't do anything. How do I need to change this expression?

```
timestep= cut -d' ' -f1 timestep
```

Comment: timestep=$(cut -d' ' -f1 timestep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer :

```
f=timestep
timestep=$(cut -d' ' -f1 $f)
echo "$timestep"
```